# How to use `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` in the Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, visual-studio-code, gtk3

How can I configure the tasks.json file so that when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> the copier will use `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`.

My file looks like this:

```
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "g++ `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": ["main.cpp"]
```

But it returns this message:
Failed to launch external program g++ `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` main.cpp. spawn g++ `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` ENOENT

If I put it as an argument, like this:

```
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "g++",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": ["main.cpp", "pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`"]
```

Returns this message:

```
g++: error: pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`: 
File or directory not found
```

Comment: you forgot the ` before pkg-config on the second alternative (as an argument). Another option would be to create a Makefile and have VS Code invoke make. I don't use VS Code that often so i may be wrong.

Comment: For the time being I created a Makefile file as you suggested.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can try this!

```
"version": "0.1.0"
"command": "g++",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": [
         "main.cpp",
         "`pkg-config", "--libs", "--cflags", "gtkmm-3.0`",
 ]
```

you should control how the argument is quoted.
more information: [Task in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)