# How to add gtk lib in Visual studio code?

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code

I try to add gtk library to my file in Visual Studio code on my Arch Linux ,but it underlines "#include  line and writes:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/mikhailkhr/My projects/C projects/Test/Test.c).
cannot open source file "glibconfig.h" (dependency of "gtk/gtk.h")
```

It does compile this file with:

```
 gcc `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags` ProgName.c `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --libs`
```

But why does it underline this?
And how to fix this?

Thanks.

Sorse code:

```
#define _PROGRAM_NAME "whoami"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

const char *getUserName()
{
  uid_t uid = geteuid();
  struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(uid);
  if (pw)
  {
    return pw->pw_name;
  }

  return "";
}

static void
print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
             gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("Hello %s\n", getUserName());
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *button_box;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

  button_box = gtk_button_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label (getUserName());
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
  g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), button);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);



    return status;

}
```

Comment: Try this documentation https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/

Comment: Then search packages names here https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php

Answer (score 6):

Add `/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include/` to the include paths.

Basically one wants to add the output from [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) to the VSCode includes.
To dump the output on a shell, use:
`echo $(pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0)`

If you want to provide `pkg-config` as a VSCode task argument see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49771627/9721479).
I am happily using this [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) with GCC and Clang.
Here is my [gist to kick off coding GTK 3 in C with VSCode.](https://gist.github.com/Acry/e0a167f6d323feb0519edb47248ab3bf)

Happy hacking!

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. Only this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58751822/2455888) works.

Comment: @haccks What do you mean by it doesnt work? This was about how to add the proper includes for GTK-3, and the other solution does the excact same thing: adding `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` to `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`. The setup depends on the toolchain one uses. Btw: [gtk4 is stable since end of 2020.](https://blog.gtk.org/2020/12/16/gtk-4-0/)

Comment: I used the same toolchain as you mentioned in the answer.`dding pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` to `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` didn't work for me. I had to modify my `task.json` and `launch.json` files too as mentioned in other answer.

Comment: @haccks You want the output, not the shell command. Read again. This Question was about missing includes. Please understand that building, compiling and debugging can be done in different ways. This solution uses VSCode as editor, not IDE.

Answer (score 5):

I added this to the include path inside `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/include/gtk-3.0",
            "/usr/include/glib-2.0",
            "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
            "/usr/include/pango-1.0",
            "/usr/include/harfbuzz",
            "/usr/include/cairo",
            "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
            "/usr/include/atk-1.0"
        ],
```

If you need gtkmm:

```
"/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0",
"/usr/include/glibmm-2.4",
"/usr/include/sigc++-2.0",
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include",
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include",
"/usr/include/giomm-2.4/giomm",
"/usr/include/giomm-2.4",
"/usr/include/glibmm-2.4",
"/usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm",
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include",
"/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0",
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include",
"/usr/include/pangomm-1.4",
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include",
"/usr/include/cairomm-1.0",
"/usr/include/freetype2",
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include",
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atkmm-1.6/include",
"/usr/include/atkmm-1.6"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open gtk/gtk.h (F12 go to definition):

[image]

You'll see a bunch of other red lines:

[image]

Which, generally saying, is your error message.

In most cases, if you open 1 of those header files , you'll see that some header path is missing (non related to `gtk/` core , `pango` in this case):

[image]

Simply search the name (`pango` as example here) under your `include` directory (mine one is C:\msys64\mingw64\include under the Windows):

[image]

Now, when you're sure it's installed (install it in case of opposite answer) you need to create `.vscode` folder under your working-project directory and create a file `c_cpp_properties.json`

[image]

In this file you will tell to VSCode, where the required header files are stored:

[image]

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
               "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [ "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\pango-1.0"         , "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\gtk-3.0" ,"C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include", "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\glib-2.0"],
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

(Full documentation about properties of the file you can find [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp))

Which solves one of the previous errors:

[image]

You should repeat and add those `pathes` into the `includePath` property untill  it will be fully solved.