VSCode can't open source file "glibconfig.h" (dependency of glib.c) ---Windows
My glib.h file is located inside of this folder: "C:\msys64\mingw64\include\glib-2.0"
This is my settings.json file:
{
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
"includePath": ["C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\glib-2.0","C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\glib-2.0\\**"]
      
}

These are all the headers I included, VSCode is only complaining with glib.h, giving the error: "cannot open source file "glibconfig.h" (dependency of "glib.h")"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <cjson/cJSON.h> 
#include <glib.h>

I am using windows so i don't know how pkg-config can be used on my machine. Which was mentioned in this awnser:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59336936

I don't exactly know yet what roles task.json and c_cpp_properties.json take in here, but to my understanding now the settings u put in there have nothing to do with the compilation of your code but are there for the intellisense. That beeing said, when I tried to compile the code it went wrong in multiple ways no matter what i put in these json files.
The compilation errors had multiple causes:

I had multiple installations of mingw64. You need to make sure that you chose the compiler of the right istallation. You can check which path gcc uses to access your compiler with this command: pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0

You need to specify the Path to your header file (#include <glib.h>) in the enviroment variables of your system (you may need to create the variable CPATH) the linker(i think thats what it is) looks for the header files that are specified in these directories (It won't look recursively so you may need to add:"C:\msys64\mingw64\include\glib-2.0" even though you already have "C:\msys64\mingw64\include" mentioned in your CPATH variable).
http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/10/windows-environment-variables-for-mingw.html
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html


(fun fact: glibconfig.h is located in "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\glib-2.0\include" while all your other headers are in here or in subdirectories from here: "C:\msys64\mingw64\include")

You need to specify libraries that you use inside the command you use to compile your project, with the -l tag. I still have to find out why.
In the following example i am telling the compiler to consider the
Ws2_32 library and the cjson library. They are acutally called
libWs2_32.a and libcjson.a and can be found under
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib on my Windows machine.
gcc quicktest.c -Wall -l Ws2_32 -l cjson -o quicktest.exe


